# While initializing react-native app on my m1 macbook device it gives cocapods error while downloading packages

Tags: javascript, macos, react-native, cocoapods, apple-m1

I'm running command npx react-native init myapp and while it initializing project gives me this error

```html
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./AwesomeProject/ios && pod install".
CocoaPods documentation: https://cocoapods.org/
```

When I try to run"cd ./AwesomeProject/ios && pod install" after error it gives me that error

```html
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:36: [BUG] Illegal instruction at 0x0000000104850000
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:                    
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                     
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                      
   for more details.                                                        
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.     

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0054 p:---- s:0314 e:000313 CFUNC  :getdtablesize
c:0053 p:0050 s:0310 e:000309 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:36
c:0052 p:0075 s:0307 e:000306 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:27
c:0051 p:0007 s:0304 e:000303 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:3
c:0050 p:0007 s:0301 e:000300 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:2 [FINISH]
c:0049 p:---- s:0298 e:000297 CFUNC  :require
c:0048 p:0110 s:0293 e:000292 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0047 p:0128 s:0281 e:000280 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curl.rb:29
c:0046 p:0007 s:0278 e:000277 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curl.rb:14
c:0045 p:0049 s:0275 e:000274 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curl.rb:9 [FINISH]
c:0044 p:---- s:0272 e:000271 CFUNC  :require
c:0043 p:0110 s:0267 e:000266 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0042 p:0049 s:0255 e:000254 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:16 [FINISH]
c:0041 p:---- s:0252 e:000251 CFUNC  :require
c:0040 p:0110 s:0247 e:000246 METHOD /
  449 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/coc

...

1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspection_result.rb
  597 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/specs_state.rb
  598 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/abstract_external_source.rb
  599 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/downloader_source.rb
  600 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb
  601 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/podspec_source.rb
  602 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/external_sources.rb
  603 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/wrap.rb
  604 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/access.rb
  605 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/extract.rb
  606 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/extract_options.rb
  607 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/grouping.rb
  608 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/symbol/starts_ends_with.rb
  609 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/array_inquirer.rb
  610 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/inquiry.rb
  611 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/array.rb
  612 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb
  613 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.11/lib/i18n/backend.rb
  614 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.11/lib/i18n/core_ext/hash.rb
  615 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.11/lib/i18n/backend/transliterator.rb
  616 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.11/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb
  617 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.11/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb
  618 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/action.rb
  619 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/add_edge_no_circular.rb
  620 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/add_vertex.rb
  621 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/delete_edge.rb
  622 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/detach_vertex_named.rb
  623 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/set_payload.rb
  624 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/tag.rb
  625 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/log.rb
  626 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/vertex.rb
  627 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph.rb
  628 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/locking_dependency_analyzer.rb
  629 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/gem_metadata.rb
  630 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/state.rb
  631 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/modules/specification_provider.rb
  632 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/resolution_state.rb
  633 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb
  634 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb
  635 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/modules/ui.rb
  636 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo.rb
  637 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver/lazy_specification.rb
  638 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver/resolver_specification.rb
  639 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb
  640 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/digest/sha2.bundle
  641 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/digest/sha2.rb
  642 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle
  643 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/platform.rb
  644 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/data_converter.rb
  645 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/types.rb
  646 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/library.rb
  647 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/errno.rb
  648 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/abstract_memory.rb
  649 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/pointer.rb
  650 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/memorypointer.rb
  651 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/struct_layout.rb
  652 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/struct_layout_builder.rb
  653 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/struct_by_reference.rb
  654 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/struct.rb
  655 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/union.rb
  656 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/managedstruct.rb
  657 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/callback.rb
  658 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/io.rb
  659 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/autopointer.rb
  660 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/variadic.rb
  661 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/enum.rb
  662 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/version.rb
  663 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi/ffi.rb
  664 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb
  665 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb
  666 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/codes.rb
  667 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/options.rb
  668 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/infos.rb
  669 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/form_options.rb
  670 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/messages.rb
  671 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/functions.rb
  672 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/constants.rb
  673 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/settings.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.

zsh: abort      pod install
beykan@alper-MacBook-Air ios %
```

I had researched a little bit but i couldn't find any helpful resource.

Comment: Can you try:

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

Then

arch -x86_64 pod install

Comment: Thank you, it seemed worked for now. It's installing now. When i got the build I'll let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Then

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```